# Partially compile Smarty template

Tags: smarty

Consider the following `Smarty` template for a generic `HTML select`

```
<select id="{$id}" name="{$name}">
{foreach $options as $option}
    <option value="{$option->id}">{$description}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```

Sometimes I want `{$description}` to be `{$option->name}`, sometimes `{$option->email} ({$option->organisation})`, or other things, depending on what the `select` is for. Is there any way to partially compile the template, setting `$description`?

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
$description = '{$option->email} ({$option->organisation})'
$tpl->assign('description', $description);
$tpl->compile(); // This should compile the assigned variables but not complain about variables that have not been assigned

$tpl->assign('id', $id);
$tpl->assign('name', $name);
$tpl->assign('value', $value);
$tpl->assign('options', $options);
$tpl->display();
```

After `$tpl->compile();`, the template should be

```
<select id="{$id}" name="{$name}">
{foreach $options as $option}
    <option value="{$option->id}">{$option->email} ({$option->organisation})</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```

so that I get the desired description. Can this be done?

Comment: Smarty doesn't work this way. On compilation, it replaces all the `Smarty` constructs enclosed in `{` and `}` with `PHP` code. It doesn't matter if the variables are assigned or not, it doesn't replace them into the compiled code. For example, `{$id}` becomes something like `<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['id']->value;?>`. The call `$tpl->assign('id', $id);` stores the value of `$id` in `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['id']->value` and when `display()` runs, it has a value to `echo()`; otherwise it will `echo()` a `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve more or less what I wanted to using a template file like this

```
<select id="{$id}" name="{$name}">
{foreach $options as $option}
    <option value="{$option->id}">{eval var=$description}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```

And a PHP file like this

```
$description = '{$option->email} ({$option->organisation})'
$tpl->assign('description', $description);
$tpl->assign('id', $id);
$tpl->assign('name', $name);
$tpl->assign('options', $options);
$tpl->display();
```

To increase performance, `{include file="string:{$description}"}` can be used instead of `{eval var=$description}`.